# array map react component call child function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

How can we call child function, if we are using array map in react? I have found a way on googling by using refs but it does not call actual component rather than the last component it registered.

> Index.jsx

```
setActiveChat = (ID) => {
    this.refs.chateditor.activateChat(ID);
}

{
   this.state.users.map((user, index) => <ChatEditor ref="chateditor"/>)
}
```

> ChatEditor.jsx

```
activateChat = (ID) => {
        alert("Hi i am here!");
}
```

Thanks @Mayank Shukla

By inspiring from his solution and to avoid usage of refs according to [DOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs) 
I have come up with a solution if anyone wants to use it.

> Index.jsx

```
    setActiveChat = (ID) => {
        this[`editor${ID}`](ID);
    }


    {
    this.state.users.map((user, index) => <ChatEditor initChat={edtr =>
     (this[`editor${user.ID}`] = edtr)} />
    }
```

> ChatEditor.jsx

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        props.initChat(this.activateChat);
    }

activateChat = (ID) => {
        alert('Hey, I m here')
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are assigning the same ref (ref name) to all the Child component, so and the end of the loop, ref will have the reference of last Child component.

Solution is, use the unique name for refs for each child, one way to achieve that is, put the index of element with the ref.

Like this:

```
this.state.users.map((user, index) => <ChatEditor ref={`chateditor${index}`} />)
```

Now use:

```
this.refs[`chateditor${index}`]     //replace index with 0,1,2...
```

To access the specific child element.

---

**Suggestion,** As per **[DOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs)**:

> If you worked with React before, you might be familiar with an older
>   API where the ref attribute is a string, like "textInput", and the DOM
>   node is accessed as this.refs.textInput. We advise against it because
>   string refs have some issues, are considered legacy, and are likely to
>   be removed in one of the future releases. If you’re currently using
>   this.refs.textInput to access refs, we recommend the callback pattern
>   instead.

So use ref callback method instead of string refs.

Like this:

```
this.state.users.map((user, index) => 
     <ChatEditor ref={el => (this[`chateditor${index}`] = el)} />)
```

Now use this to access the Child component:

```
this[`chateditor${index}`]          //replace index with 0,1,2...
```

Comment: Interesting that you show the code according to the old api, but write a warning that one should use callbacks instead (without added code)

Comment: hehe, you want me to write the code for that also :P, will do that :)